# Deleting Rows in R that are similar to other rows

Tags: r, rows

I was unsure as to how to word this question because in some sense, the rows that I want deleted are technically duplicate rows, but contain different in data in some columns. I am sure some solution to this problem exists, but I was unable to find it.

```
      inning outs balls strikes pitchSeq   batter    eventNum
101      6    2     0       2        F    sandp001      49     
102      6    2     0       2        F    sandp001      49      
104      6    2     0       2        B    sandp001      49 


      inning outs balls strikes pitchSeq   batter   eventNum
105      6    2     2       2        F    sandp001      50  
106      6    2     2       2        F    sandp001      50  
108      6    2     2       2        B    sandp001      50  
110      6    2     2       2        B    sandp001      50  
111      6    2     2       2        S    sandp001      50
```

There are about 90 other columns with relevant information, but I was wondering if there is a general R function or command that I can use to delete the first three rows from the second table excerpt since they represent the same results. There are several of situations in my table with differing numbers of rows. Ideally, I could use something that I could put into source code since I will have to do this over a few hundred different files.

Comment: Please be more specific about the rules that determine whether a row should be deleted or not. What is (a) the data you have and (b) the desired output?

Comment: This is called an "anti-join" if you looking for a search term. Both the `dplyr`  (via `dplyr::anti_join`) and `data.table` packages (via `DT1[!DT2]` ) can cope with this.

Comment: @sethpottle Why only first `3` will be deleted? Other 2 rows have similar information. What is criteria for deletion or duplicate decision?

Comment: @hplieninger The first 3 rows (101, 102 104) are a series of pitches during a baseball game. The first 3 rows of the second excerpt (105, 106, 108) represent those same three pitches. The difference between them is that an event happened during the 3rd pitch (104/108), causing the that event to be recorded in the data separately from the end result of the 2nd excerpt. I want to replace the first 3 rows in the 2nd excerpt (105, 106, 108) with the first series of rows (101, 102, 104). There are several instances of this in the data with varying numbers of rows, so something universal is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unique()` function to remove duplicates. Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- bind_rows(mtcars[1, ], head(mtcars)) #creating a small data frame with a duplicate row

dat
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
3 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
4 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
5 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
6 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
7 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

First two rows of **dat** are duplicates. Use `unique()` to remove the duplicate row.

```
unique(dat)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

You can further specify columns for unique to look at.

For example, `unique(dat[, -c("hp", "vs)])`